# Why KEY has automatically created when I make fk constraint for field?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, foreign-keys

I am creating the table with this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE movies_genres 
(
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    movie_id INT NOT NULL,
    genre_id INT NOT NULL,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_movie_id` FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_genre_id` FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES genres(id),
    CONSTRAINT unique_id_pair UNIQUE(movie_id, genre_id)
);
```

But then I look at the info about the table in MySQL Workbench I see:

```
CREATE TABLE `movies_genres` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movie_id` int NOT NULL,
  `genre_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_id_pair` (`movie_id`,`genre_id`),
  KEY `fk_genre_id` (`genre_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_genre_id` FOREIGN KEY (`genre_id`) REFERENCES `genres` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movie_id` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movies` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Why this line of code has generated?

```
KEY `fk_genre_id` (`genre_id`)
```

Also I see that extra index was created that I didn't order...

[Screenshot with extra index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0ZN1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html says:

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
> foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
> referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
> columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. **Such an
> index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
> exist.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: So, I assume that MySQL created the index for one of the foreign keys automatically. But why for only just one? I have 2 foreign keys.

Comment: It had to create the index on `genre_id` but your UNIQUE KEY with `movie_id` as the first column was sufficient to use for the foreign key. Read the wording in that documentation excerpt again: "**...if it does not exist.**"

Answer (score 1):

(Bill gave the answer; this is providing another tip.)

Get rid of `id` from the table and change to these two indexes:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`,`genre_id`),
KEY `fk_genre_id` (`genre_id`),
```

That will make some of your uses of this many-to-many table run faster.  It will also shrink the table size.

**If need id**

Since you need `id` for single-row deletion and updating, keep `id`, but use

```
PRIMARY KEY (id)
INDEX(`movie_id`, `genre_id`),
INDEX(`genre_id`, `movie_id`),
```

The PK will continue to make Delete/Update efficient; the other two indexes will make the many-to-many JOIN efficient.

Comment: I don't want because it's easier to `DELETE` or `UPDATE` this row with `WHERE` by `id`.

Comment: @KirillDevope - I added to my Answer.

Comment: Why do you have index for the each combination of the pair?

Comment: @KirillDevope - One index makes it efficient to look up the genres for a set of movies; the other makes it efficient to look up the movies for a genre.  (It is typical for a many-to-many relationship to be used in both directions.)